# Implement auto-complete search with Postgres index-only scan on GIN index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

I have a Ruby on Rails app that accesses a Postgres database containing a table named `statements`. This table has a text field called `statement_text` which is GIN-indexed using the following expression:

```
CREATE INDEX index_statement_text ON statements USING gin (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE(statement_text, ''::text)));
```

I've created a form to search the contents of the `statement_text` field, and the resulting search successfully uses the GIN index to display results.

I'm now trying to go one step further and implement autocomplete -- i.e. when the user types a minimum of, say, 4 characters in the search form (e.g. "yank"), the text box will display a dropdown list of autocomplete suggestions based on all the matching tsvectors in the index (for example, "yankees").

Every time I do this, Postgres not only scans the index ("Bitmap Index Scan") but also queries the `statement_text` field itself ("Bitmap Heap Scan"), which is completely unnecessary and relatively slow: I don't want it to actually pull the fields, just the tsvectors.

How can I force Postgres to run an index-only scan on this GIN index?

Comment: What's the query you're sending for the autocomplete check?

Comment: @jmelesky Statement.select("to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(\"statements\".\"statement_text\"::text, ''))").where("to_tsquery('simple', 'sox') @@ to_tsvector('simple', coalesce(\"statements\".\"statement_text\"::text, ''))").explain

Comment: @jmelesky Of course, eventually I'll include the prefix tsearch option as well, but to keep it as simple as possible I'm only matching on whole tsvectors for now. And even so, it's not doing an index-only scan.